# How are videos for this half cube screen set up to look 3D?

Tags: video, graphics, 3d, rendering, screen

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lf3GwPK5mCc I understand the skewing and that it will only look like this from an angle. BUT, I am having trouble understanding how to create a video like this. In fact, I tried doing it on a still image and still could not manage to understand this perspective. Seems to involve skew and perspective that take into account the angle from where it is planned to be seen from. Help from experts will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the skew of the video should be according to the geometry of each side of the screen.

Comment: We solved some time ago and came up with a great art piece of a 3D bar ceiling.